# Problem amount!

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

There was a problem with the calculation of amounts
I converted the Main Amount:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H^3_n}{2^n}&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n}\left ( H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right )^3=\\[0.1in]
&\;=2\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{H_n^3}{2^n}-6\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{H^2_n}{n2^2}+6\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{H_n}{n^22^n}-2\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^32^n}=\\[0.1in]
&\;=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H^3_n}{2^n}-6\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H^2_n}{n2^n}+6\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_n}{n^22^n}-2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^32^n}
\end{align}
I can't calculate these amounts. I don't want to use Polylogarithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)

How can these sums be calculated without Polylogarithms?

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a proof.*

*I know the result (it is in my cookbook) but I do not remember where I took it from (age problem, I suppose)*

If you consider $$a_n=\frac{H^3_n}{2^n}$$ the convergence is quite fast since, for large values of $n$,
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2 n (\log (n)+\gamma )}$$ Computing
$$S_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10^k }\frac{H^3_n}{2^n}$$ for $k=3$ we already have more than $150$ exact significant figures. The numerical value is
$$3.59342794177494296025518240703339219591695480351933893769738611918882\cdots$$ which is
$$\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H^3_n}{2^n}=\zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3} \log (2) \left(\pi ^2+\log ^2(2)\right)}$$